# Duplicates in custom array shuffle for cipher alphabet

Tags: java, encryption

I have an assignment to generate a random cipher alphabet and then encrypt and decrypt the message inputted by the user. While the encryption and input is working, the decryption is returning the wrong message. Upon further investigation, I discovered this is because my shuffled cipher alphabet has duplicates. I attempted to fix the duplicate error by providing a "swapped = true" method to not replace a letter that had already been shuffled. However, this just added holes and therefore I removed that. Below is the code for my method that returns duplicates.

```
 public static char[] cipherAlphabet(char[] alpha)
{
   Random rand = new Random();
   char[] newAlpha = new char[26];
   char current;
   int index;
   for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i +=1)
   {

       index = rand.nextInt(alpha.length);
       newAlpha[i] = alpha[index];
       newAlpha[index] = alpha[i];
   }


   return newAlpha;
}
```

When I input the message

```
sample message
```

This returns an encryption of

```
Encrypted Message:  WUFKRJ FJWWUMJ
```

and a decoded message of

```
 samcle message
```

I am not sure why this is off by one letter but there are definitely problems with my alphabet, as it looks like this.

```
Regular Alphabet: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Cipher Alphabet: ulktjvmihqyrfxnkjlwdzwvzkx
                 TWO Ws and Js     ^  ^
```

Any help with an idea of where to go or code would be appreciated.

EDIT: For people suggesting Collections.shuffle(), I am Required to use Random for this assignment.

Comment: `newAlpha[i] = alpha[index]; newAlpha[index] = alpha[i];` - this makes them have the same values, not swaps them

Comment: `newAlpha` and `alpha` are different arrays, however. `newAlpha` is an empty array so I am filling its indexes with values from a different array. Thanks and I will try this.

Comment: Then I'd suggest simply copying the content of `alpha` to `newAlpha` and randomly swapping the content of `newAlpha` using the logic provided by my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest such solution:

```
static Random rand = new Random();

public static char[] cipherAlphabet(char[] alpha) {

    // copy of alpha
    char[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(alpha, alpha.length);

    // linear time O(n)
    for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i += 1) {
        // random index
        int j = rand.nextInt(alpha.length);

        // swap
        char temp = copy[j];
        copy[j] = copy[i];
        copy[i] = temp;

    }

    return copy;
}
```

This algo takes exactly n steps, where n is length of alphabet.

In each iteration you generate randomly new index (j),
then swap i-th and j-th elements.

No matter how many swaps you perform, the alphabet has no duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You implemented the swapping logic incorrectly. This:

```
index = rand.nextInt(alpha.length);
newAlpha[i] = alpha[index];
newAlpha[index] = alpha[i];
```

Makes both `i`th and `index`th values be equal to the `index`th element. To swap them, you have to introduce the temporary variable, like so:

```
index = rand.nextInt(alpha.length);
int tmp = newAlpha[i];
newAlpha[i] = alpha[index];
newAlpha[index] = tmp;
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work since `newAlpha` and `alpha` are different arrays. `newAlpha` is an empty array that I am filling with values from `alpha`. This solution creates more duplicates.

Comment: Copy the content of `alpha` to `newAlpha`, then randomly swap `newAlpha`'s indexes using the above solution then

Comment: Ok thanks that works, solved by other answer as well. Upvoted :).